# Fully understand for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I start out with a small code example right away:

```
def foo():
    return 0

a = [1, 2, 3]

for el in a:
    el = foo()

print(a) # [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like to know what ***el*** is in this case. As ***a*** remains the same, I intuite that ***el*** is a reference to an int. But after reassigning it, el points to a new int object that has nothing to do with the list ***a*** anymore.

Please tell me, if I understand it correctly. Furthermore, how do you get around this pythonic-ly? is *enumerate()* the right call as

```
for i, el in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = foo()
```

works fine.

Comment: To the extent that the question isn't answered by the linked duplicate, it lacks focus or is unclear (what exactly are we trying to "get around"? Was `el = foo()` intended to modify `a`? If so, was that the intended primary question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood this correctly. `for` sets the target variable `el` to point to each of the elements in `a`. `el = foo()` indeed then updates that name to point to a different, unrelated integer.

Using `enumerate()` is a good way to replace the references in `a` instead.

In this context, you may find the [*Facts and myths about Python names and values* article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder helpful.

Another way would be to create a new list object altogether and re-bind `a` to point to that list. You could build such a list with a list comprehension:

```
a = [foo() for el in a]
```